# Can't support both OpenMP v4 and v5 in GCC

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I've come across an unusual problem in trying to make my C/C++ project support both gcc-8 (with OpenMP 4.5) and gcc-9 (with OpenMP 5.0). It is caused by variables defined as `const` which are to be shared between threads.

For example, here's some code compatible with OpenMP 5, but fails with OpenMP 4.5 (with error `'x' is predetermined 'shared' for 'shared'`):

```
const x = 10;
int i;

# pragma omp parallel \
    default  (none) \
    shared   (x) \
    private  (i)
{
# pragma omp for schedule (static)
    for (i=0; i<x; i++)
        // etc
}
```

The above turns out also to be compatible with `clang-10`, though not `clang-3.7`.

Here's the same code (just excluding `x` from `shared`) compatible with OpenMP 4.5, but fails with OpenMP 5 (with error `error: 'numTasks' not specified in enclosing 'parallel'`):

```
const x = 10;
int i;

# pragma omp parallel \
    default  (none) \
    private  (i)
{
# pragma omp for schedule (static)
    for (i=0; i<x; i++)
        // etc
}
```

It seems like OpenMP 5 no longer intelligently assumes that `const` variables are shared. The only code which can compile on both is one which needlessly puts `x` in `firstprivate`:

```
const x = 10;
int i;

# pragma omp parallel \
    default  (none) \
    firstprivate (x) \
    private  (i)
{
# pragma omp for schedule (static)
    for (i=0; i<x; i++)
        // etc
}
```

This seems a poor solution, since now I'm paying to copy `x` into every thread when it's never going to be modified! Note also I cannot make `x` non-`const`, since it's actually a `const` argument to a calling function.

What's the deal, and what's the correct/efficient way to make agnostic code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porting to `gcc-9` is addressed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/porting_to.html#ompdatasharing). To maintain compatability with both versions of OpenMP, I'll have to either:

- remove `default (none)`
- remove all `const`